# React Router navigation using history push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new to ReactJS. I stuck with React routing when i tried to navigate from one page to another page history.push('/newpage') is not working for me. Login service call success i want navigate to another page.

I am using below version

"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../Login/Login.css';
import {Auth} from '../../services/Api';
// import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            userName: '',
            password: ''
        }
        this.changeEventReact = this.changeEventReact.bind(this);
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    }
    changeEventReact = (e) =>{
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
        // console.log(this.state);
    }
    login = e=>{
        // console.log(this.state);
        Auth('login', this.state)
        .then((result)=>{
            let responseJSON = result;
            if(responseJSON.data.id != ''){
                console.log("Login success");
                const history = useHistory();
                let path = `/facilityRegister`; 
                history.push(path);
            }else{
                console.log('Login failed');
            }
        });
    }
```

We can use below three methods to do this

```
1. history.push('/facilityRegister')
2. <Redirect to='/facilityRegister'/>
3. window.location.href("/facilityRegister')
```

window.location.href is working as expected. But history.push and  is not working.

Let me know what I missed.

Comment: try with this.props.history.push('/path')

Comment: @VyasArpit: Tried with this.props.history.push('/path'); is not working. In class component we can't use history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to react [faq](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both):

> You can’t use Hooks inside a class component

That's why `const history = useHistory();` is not working here. But anyway you [can't use hooks inside async functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). Use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC instead or try to rewrite your component to functional.

Answer (score 2):

well as say before hooks can not be use in class components and can only be use in function components like this

```
const app = (props) => {
     const history = useHistory();
     history.push("/path");
}
```

you can try this  `props.history.push("/path")`

hope it's help :)

Comment: I Tried to convert class component to functional component and its throwing error.  React Hook "useHistory" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks. Below is class component method call.

const login = e=>{
                console.log("Login success");
                const history = useHistory();
                let path = `/facilityRegister`; 
                history.push(path);
    }